# For loop inside a for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

This is a question on a test I have, I'm having trouble understanding the solution which is:

```
01
12
23
```

(Which is the output of the program below)

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
            printf("%d", i+j);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Can anyone explain why this happens? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: If you want to understand how code works, pretend you're the computer and execute it by hand, writing the variable values down on paper as you go.

Comment: You'll learn it much better that way than by trying to read someone's explanation, I guarantee it.

Comment: @Barmar Voted up your comment :) I used to do this a lot, writing on paper for each loop :)

Comment: Replacing the `"%d"` format by `"%d "` might make it clearer what's going on.

Comment: user3241425 i guess you are confused by printf("\n");

Answer (score 1):

@Barmar is right but maybe you don't know how to substitute yourself as a computer.

Let me show you how I would do it myself.

I get to the inner loop and see that j successively is 0, 1. In the other hand, i is a constant for that loop.

Within the inner loop, we simply display the sum i+j as a digit, two times, that is i+0 followed by i+1, then print new line.

Now, the outer loop increments i from 0, 1, 2 successively.

As for the inner loop, I apply what I've found, and the program will end up, successively with:

01 
12
23

Hope it helps.